# get machnine name in same network using php codeigniter using netapi32.dll with netserverenum function

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I want to retrieve machnine name in same network using php codeigniter with the function netsererenum (from netapi32.dll). I am using php5.5.12 on apache. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a little executable and run it with the [exec()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php) function. Otherwise, it will probably not be that easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for ur  reply at the mean time i used netapi32.dll from system. I added the extension in php.ini file but it is not supported. so can u guide me.Anybody explain me the proper way to do it...?

Comment: Before use the exec() function , i want to know how to use netapi32.dll in php codeigniter. Is it possible to collect the machine name in same network using dll file. Please provide relevant answer only.